# EF relationship to slow changing dimension

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using C# with .net 4.5.1 and EF 6 code first.

Is there a way to mark relationships with a time range of validity? In terms of SQL DDL I'd define something like this:

```
create table a_b_relationship (
  table_a_id int,
  table_b_id int,
  valid_from datetime,
  valid_to datetime
)
```

I'm wondering if I should define the relationship itself as a class so that EF translate it in a relationship-table or there is a data annotation or fluent api.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using database first, or code first EF?

Comment: @Shriike he wrote code first in the begining

Comment: Thanks @mybirthname I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add properties in the table created to support a many-to-many relationship between to tables.

I would create a separate class to support this.

```
public class a_b_relationship 
{
  public a_b_relationship_id(table_a a, table_b b)
  {
    table_a = a;
    table_b = b;
    ValidTime(20);
  }

  public int a_b_relationship_id { get; set; }
  public int table_a_id { get; set; }
  public int table_b_id { get; set; }
  public DateTime valid_from { get; set; }
  public DateTime valid_to { get; set; }

  public virtual IEnumerable<table_a> table_as { get; set; }
  public virtual IEnumerable<table_b> table_bs { get; set; }


  private void ValidTime(int validMinutes)
  {
    valid_from = DateTime.Now();
    valid_to = DateTime.Now().AddMinutes(validMinutes);
  }
}
```

Then map this in your context.

This way you can add the extra properties for the validity DateTimes instead of letting EF generate the joining table without them.

If you are trying to set the relationship time range in EF (e.g. When I link a record in table_a to a record in table_b, then this relationship is valid for 2 hours), then no.  That is a business rule that you set in code.

### Edit

I added a method for adding the time range of validity that's accessed when creating the relationship.  You still need to save the changes & all that, but this is just an example of how I would do it.  You could set this up to work from either or both a & b classes.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid ( something like class a -> class relationship -> class b instead of class a -> class b). EF do not support relationship attributes ?

Comment: Although I don't consider my self an expert, I do think the setup I have described here works into how you customise an EF many-to-many relationship.  If you didn't need the customisation, EF would generate a_b_relationship table.  What are you trying to achieve that this won't work for?

Comment: I'd preferred not to have a separate entity to represent the relationship but I understand this is correct and the only way to go. Marking this as solved, thanks